# proving a matrix inequality with perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Problem:
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be nonsingular and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $Ax = b$ and $(A + \delta A)(x + \delta x) = b$ with $||A^{-1}\delta A||<1$.

Show that
$\frac{||\delta x||}{||x||} \leq \frac{||A^{-1} \delta A||}{1-||A^{-1} \delta A||}$

I have tried proving this by substituting $x=A^{-1}b$ = $A^{-1}(A + \delta A)(x + \delta x)$

which yields

$\frac{||\delta x||}{||x||}= \frac{||\delta A^{-1}(A + \delta A)(x + \delta x)||}{||A^{-1}(A + \delta A)(x + \delta x)||}
\\=\frac{||\delta A^{-1}(A + \delta A)||}{||A^{-1}(A + \delta A)||}\\
         =\frac{||\delta A^{-1}A + \delta A^{-1}\delta A||}{||A^{-1}A + A^{-1}\delta A||}
\\=\frac{||\delta A^{-1}A + I||}{||I + A^{-1}\delta A||}.$

It's likely that I am making some mistakes but I wanted to get some feedback on the direction I am going.

Comment: There is no guarantee that $δA$ is invertible. I doubt that the algebra that lead to that expression is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should get
$$
Ax=Ax+ δA\,x+(A+ δA)\,δx\implies -A^{-1}δAx=(I+A^{-1}δA)\,δx
$$
and by the theory of the Neumann series
$$
\|(I-B)^{-1}\|\le(1-\|B\|)^{-1}\\~\\
\implies
\|δx\|\le\frac{\|A^{-1}δA\|}{1-\|A^{-1}δA\|}\|x\|
$$